# How can I use getSharedPreferences in my custom SettingsPreferences class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, sharedpreferences

So I have a custom `SettingsPreferences` class that has a few methods that I want to access from my `Settings` class (generated by Android Studio) when a setting is changed in my app.

Currently, I do this as below:

**From my Settings class**

```
 public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

        final Preference audioCodec = findPreference("codec");
        assert audioCodec != null;
        audioCodec.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String audioInputValue = newValue.toString();
                new SettingsPreferences().handleAudioCodecChange(audioInputValue);
                return true;
            }
        }); ....
```

**From my custom class**

```
public void handleAudioCodecChange(String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor codecEditor = settings.edit();
    switch (value) {
        case "1":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 1);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "2":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 2);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "3":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 3);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "4":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 4);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "5":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 5);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "6":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 6);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
        case "7":
            codecEditor.putInt("codec", 7);
            codecEditor.apply();
            break;
    } ....
```

However, the way in which I would retrieve the preferences file in my other classes (shown below) does not work.

```
// sharedPrefs for remembering settings
final static String PREFERENCES_NAME = "settingsFile";
SharedPreferences settings = null;

settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
```

I tried to remedy this by adding the constructor below to my custom class:

```
public SettingsPreferences(Context context) {
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
}
```

But this then requires me to pass a context to my class call in:  `new SettingsPreferences().handleAudioCodecChange(audioInputValue);`

If I put `getContext()` in it like this, `SettingsPreferences(getContext()).handleAudioCodecChange(audioInputValue);` will my problem be fixed? It says that `getContext()` may be null.

I have included below the full code for both classes in case it is needed.

**Settings class**

```
package com.voicerecorderproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }


    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

            final Preference audioCodec = findPreference("codec");
            assert audioCodec != null;
            audioCodec.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    String audioInputValue = newValue.toString();
                    new SettingsPreferences().handleAudioCodecChange(audioInputValue);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final Preference outputFormat = findPreference("outputFormat");
            assert outputFormat != null;
            outputFormat.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    String outputInputValue = newValue.toString();
                    new SettingsPreferences().handleOutputFormatChange(outputInputValue);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final Preference sampleRate = findPreference("sampleRate");
            assert sampleRate != null;
            sampleRate.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    String sampleRateValue = newValue.toString();
                    new SettingsPreferences().handleSampleRateChange(sampleRateValue);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final Preference bitRate = findPreference("bitRate");
            assert bitRate != null;
            bitRate.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    String bitRateValue = newValue.toString();
                    new SettingsPreferences().handleBitRateChange(bitRateValue);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    }
```

**SettingsPreferenes Class**

```
package com.voicerecorderproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;


public class SettingsPreferences {

    // sharedPrefs for remembering settings
    final static String PREFERENCES_NAME = "settingsFile";
    SharedPreferences settings = null;

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void handleBitRateChange(String bitRateValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor bitEditor = settings.edit();
        switch(bitRateValue) {
            case "1":
                bitEditor.putInt("bitRate", 1);
                bitEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "2":
                bitEditor.putInt("bitRate", 2);
                bitEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "3":
                bitEditor.putInt("bitRate", 3);
                bitEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "4":
                bitEditor.putInt("bitRate", 4);
                bitEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "5":
                bitEditor.putInt("bitRate", 5);
                bitEditor.apply();
                break;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void handleSampleRateChange(String sampleRateValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor sampleEditor = settings.edit();
        switch (sampleRateValue) {
            case "1":
                sampleEditor.putInt("sampleRate", 1);
                sampleEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "2":
                sampleEditor.putInt("sampleRate", 2);
                sampleEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "3":
                sampleEditor.putInt("sampleRate", 3);
                sampleEditor.apply();
                break;
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void handleOutputFormatChange(String outputInputValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor formatEditor = settings.edit();
        switch (outputInputValue) {
            case "1":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 1);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "2":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 2);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "3":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 3);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "4":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 4);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "5":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 5);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "6":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 6);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "7":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 7);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "8":
                formatEditor.putInt("outputFormat", 8);
                formatEditor.apply();
                break;
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void handleAudioCodecChange(String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor codecEditor = settings.edit();
        switch (value) {
            case "1":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 1);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "2":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 2);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "3":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 3);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "4":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 4);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "5":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 5);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "6":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 6);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
            case "7":
                codecEditor.putInt("codec", 7);
                codecEditor.apply();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem is just how to access context anywhere, right? Because you have context then you can get the shared preferences. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892448/how-to-pass-context

Comment: Yes I suppose that is the problem. I didn't see it like that I was viewing it as a SharedPreferences problem. Thank you @LoWaiKiu I will try this tomorrow